# Twilio JS API - Sending an Animated Gif

Tags: javascript, meteor, twilio

My code seeks to send an MMS. I'm not able to pass in the property `mediaUrl`, which [according to the docs](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/rest/sending-messages), is what I'm looking for.

My code looks like this...

```
function sendText() {
  let sid = 'ACxxxxxxxxxxxxxx';
  let authToken = '880xxxxxxxxxxx';
  twilio = Twilio(sid, authToken);
  twilio.sendSms({
    to: "+16471111111",
    from: "+1647111111",
    body: "lol!",
    mediaUrl: findGif()
  }, function(error, responseData) {
    if (error) {
      console.log(error);
    } else {
      console.log(responseData);
    }
  });
}

// findGif() successfully returns a url with an animated GIF

function findGif() {
  giphy.random('superman', function(error, result) {
    //console.log(result);
    return result.data.image_url;
  });
}
```

Looking at my server logs, I can see there's never a field for `mediaUrl`. It's also worth noting I'm experimenting with this service through the trial account. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`sendSms` uses the deprecated /SMS/Messages endpoint on the REST API rather than the newer /Messages endpoint. There's another function called `sendMessage` which uses this newer endpoint, which you should use instead. This is capable of sending MMS messages.

Note that with a trial account, you can only send messages to verified phone numbers (e.g. your own mobile phone that you verified on signup).